# Meteor and selection-menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Meteor says you can just install node modules via `meteor npm i selection-menu --save` and they will just work. However, when I try and use [SelectionMenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selection-menu) via `new SelectionMenu({...})`, it gives me an error.

```
selection-menu.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'SelectionMenu' of undefined
```

The code in question **from the library** which throws the error looks like this:

```js
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    } else {
        root.SelectionMenu = factory();   // this is where it fails
    }
}(this, function () {
  //something here
  
});
```

I presume this is about the loader code which the library delivers and probably doesn't get along with Meteor? What can I do here, I'm confused.

My code:

```
    import SelectionMenu from 'selection-menu';
    new SelectionMenu({
        container: document.getElementById("#document"),
        content: '<a href="#test">test</a>',
        handler: function(e) {
            console.log("i selected something");
        }
    })
```

***EDIT*** I just created a clone of the library within my directory and load it from there. That's working but not ideal by any means. If you come up with any more ideas, let me know.

Comment: Have you imported the package into your file? `import SelectionMenu from 'selection-menu'` ?

Comment: @MaxG. the same part of the library fails if I do that

Comment: @MaxG. also see the added code

Answer (score 0):

It tells you `Cannot set property 'SelectionMenu' of undefined`. So there is something wrong with how you're trying to use the library.

You need to initialize things when the related component/template renders, if you haven't already.

In blaze (try this one, it might work.):

```
import SelectionMenu from 'selection-menu';

Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
    new SelectionMenu({
        container: document.getElementById("#document"),
        content: '<a href="#test">test</a>',
        handler: function(e) {
            console.log("i selected something");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The error is not in my code, but in the library. The part I showed is the first lines from the library .js file. https://github.com/iDoRecall/selection-menu/tree/gh-pages/src

Comment: @Yorrd Did you simply put that in your code like in your question or did you initialize in onRendered() as you should? I don't think this is caused by the library.

Comment: I'm using synthesis (polymer), not blaze, but I put it in the Polymer ready() function which is roughly the equivalent. However, the error appears on importing the library already before even reaching that code.